Flag all bosses in meeting based on org tree
My task is to flag "boss level" participants in data collected from meetings, based on a given org chart.
In other words, it needs to identify the highest ranked individual(s) within the given meeting, the "boss", within the reporting line (branch or subtree in the org tree).
If participants have no boss involved (within their subtree / reporting structure), they become the boss.
If there is a boss present (within their subtree / reporting structure), they are not the boss.
Meetings can have multiple bosses (when they are not on the same branch of the tree).
So the employee closest to the root is the boss, and all his superiors would not be the boss in the meeting, in case they are present.
Tools: SQL Server (Version 2019 or higher)
Org chart tree: Org Chart
Org chart data:



Name
Superior




Root
NULL


Billy
Root


Jacob
Billy


Susan
Billy


Tracy
Billy


Sheri
Billy


Carlos
Tracy


Andrew
Tracy


Hunter
Sheri


Charly
Root


Larry
Charly


Harry
Charly


Toni
Charly


Chris
Larry


Michael
Harry


Anita
Toni



Meeting data and expected results (Boss):



Meeting
Name
Meeting Boss  (expected results)




Meeting 1
Tracy
Y


Meeting 1
Hunter
Y


Meeting 2
Billy
Y


Meeting 2
Charly
Y


Meeting 2
Hunter
N


Meeting 2
Larry
N


Meeting 3
Billy
Y


Meeting 3
Hunter
N


Meeting 3
Anita
Y


Meeting 4
Anita
Y


Meeting 4
Billy
Y


Meeting 5
Anita
Y


Meeting 6
Billy
Y


Meeting 6
Charly
Y




My guess is that a recursive CTE might be needed here, but wonder if there are simpler methods to get this done.
Also interested in the commonly used terminology to describe this problem.
Thank you!

Test data:
Select *
From
(
    values
        ('Root', NULL),
        ('Billy', 'Root'),
        ('Jacob', 'Billy'),
        ('Susan', 'Billy'),
        ('Tracy', 'Billy'),
        ('Sheri', 'Billy'),
        ('Carlos', 'Tracy'),
        ('Andrew', 'Tracy'),
        ('Hunter', 'Sheri'),
        ('Charly', 'Root'),
        ('Larry', 'Charl'),
        ('Harry', 'Charly'),
        ('Toni', 'Charly'),
        ('Chris', 'Larry'),
        ('Michael', 'Harry'),
        ('Anita', 'Toni')
) A (Name, Superior)


Select *
From
(
    values
        ('Meeting 1', 'Tracy', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 1', 'Hunter', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 2', 'Billy', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 2', 'Charly', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 2', 'Hunter', 'N'),
        ('Meeting 2', 'Larry', 'N'),
        ('Meeting 3', 'Billy', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 3', 'Hunter', 'N'),
        ('Meeting 3', 'Anita', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 4', 'Anita', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 4', 'Billy', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 5', 'Anita', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 6', 'Billy', 'Y'),
        ('Meeting 6', 'Charly', 'Y')
) A ([Meeting], [Name], [Meeting Boss  (expected results)])


This is easily solvable by a WHERE EXISTS against a recursive cte that has the hierarchy of the employees. If you provide the hierarchy in a text table format, it will simplify writing the answer

What are your expected results? Can you explain your rules better? Would the answer be: any meeting participant who has no superior (anyone above them in the org chart hierarchy) also present? This could mean that meetings may have more than one "boss". Does the "Boss" flag supersede other logic, meaning all participating bosses are all included in the results, even is one reports to another?

@siggemannen thank you! I added the org tree as a text table.

@TN Sorry for not being precise enough, I added more lingo to the post. Maybe in very simple terms: in needs to flag the highest ranked employees present in a meeting, but only within their line of reporting.

Added sql to create test data

so your test data is in 2 tables, I am confused what is the expected result that should come from these 2 tables

@GuidoG check  [Meeting Boss (expected results)] field in the 2nd table

@DataDude Yes I see that, but it is not calculated or anything, it is just data in the second table, so the question stands, what are you trying to do ? What is the logic you are trying to implement ? What is your expected result ?

@GuidoG sorry, not sure what I can add to it to make it more clear for you. As it says, this is the task:
"In other words, it needs to identify the highest ranked individual(s) within the given meeting, the "boss", within the reporting line (branch or subtree in the org tree)."
The 2nd table has the expected results.
Maybe look at the provided answer below and to the run the fiddle thing. Cheers

But in the second table all columns are set manually, so there is nothing to find out, nothing to query for, nothing to calculate. I guess it's me but I find this confusing

@GuidoG the column "Meeting Boss (expected results)" is the one which needs to be calculated. I did it in my head and added the "expected results". :-)

I can think of two approaches, but both will require a recursive CTE to walk the hierarchy.
One approach is to start with each participant and use a recursive CTE to walk the hierarchy in search of a superior who is also attending the same meeting. If found, the starting participant is not a boss. If none are found, that participant is a boss.
WITH AttendeeSuperiors AS (
    SELECT M.Meeting, M.Participant, M.Expected, O.Superior
    FROM MeetingData M
    JOIN OrgChart O
        ON O.Employee = M.Participant

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ATS.Meeting, ATS.Participant, ATS.Expected, O.Superior
    FROM AttendeeSuperiors ATS
    JOIN OrgChart O
        ON O.Employee = ATS.Superior
)
SELECT
    ATS.Meeting, ATS.Participant, ATS.Expected,
    CASE WHEN MAX(M2.Participant) IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Boss
FROM AttendeeSuperiors ATS
LEFT JOIN MeetingData M2
    ON M2.Meeting = ATS.Meeting
    AND M2.Participant = ATS.Superior
GROUP BY ATS.Meeting, ATS.Participant, ATS.Expected
ORDER BY ATS.Meeting, ATS.Participant;

(There may be a slight performance advantage in checking for superior participation within the CTE, so that we can stop the recursion on first match. See the linked demo for a modified version.)
Another approach is to use a recursive CTE to build a complete list of all superiors for each employee. (Ideally, this could be written to a table and indexed for efficient repeated use.) Next, for each meeting participant, we would search that superior list for one that is also an attendee of the same meeting. If found, the starting participant is not a boss. If none are found, that participant is a boss.
WITH EmployeeSuperiors AS (
    SELECT O.Employee, O.Superior
    FROM OrgChart O
    --WHERE O.Employee IN (SELECT DISTINCT Participant FROM MeetingData) 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT S.Employee, O.Superior
    FROM EmployeeSuperiors S
    JOIN OrgChart O
        ON O.Employee = S.Superior
)
SELECT
    M.*,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM EmployeeSuperiors S
            JOIN MeetingData M2
                ON M2.Meeting = M.Meeting
                AND M2.Participant = S.Superior
            WHERE S.Employee = M.Participant
        ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Boss
FROM MeetingData M
ORDER BY M.Meeting, M.Participant;

If we are calculating EmployeeSuperiors on-the-fly for each execution (and not persisting that data), we can limit that calculation to just those employees participating in the meetings by uncommenting the WHERE condition above.
As for which approach is more efficient, I believe the first version may be better for a small number of meetings and participants relative to the total number of employees. The second approach may be better if you will be processing many meetings and have the ability to define,  populate, index, and maintain a persistent EmployeeSuperiors table. In any case, I suggest that you run your own performance tests.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
